# How to receive a string array variable from String array variable of Form in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am having an attribute of type String array.
i have to get the values of that variable in javascript defined on same page to check its validation.

Comment: Code snippets would be nice, also some better explanation. It's not very useful getting a solution to a guessed issue.

Comment: And maybe a meaningful question

Answer (score 0):

To have values of a variable in Javascript defined in the same page, the solution is to define them in the same page, otherwise they would not work.

For example

Page 1

```
...
var values = { ...whatever... }
...
```

Page 2

```
...
alert(values);
...
```

Will not work,
But, assuming that you want to do the validation process in Page 2.

Page 1

```
...
...
```

Page 2

```
...
var values = { ...whatever... }
alert(values);
...
```

...will work.
In case you want the values in both pages, the following example applies then.

Page 1

```
...
var values = { ...whatever... }
alert(values);
...
```

Page 2

```
...
var values = { ...whatever... }
alert(values);
...
```

Greetings.